# What strategies are there for winning the challenge race: Fiat 500 trial mountain circuit?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

How to win gold on challenge race: Fiat 500 trial mountain circuit? How can I exploit the regulations of this car to the max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to at least manage 2nd place:

- Lighten the car as much as possible, then add ballast to fulfill requirements. Why do that? You can get almost 50/50 weight distribution.
- Tune the car and then use a limiter to the down to the allowed HP. With extreme tuning, the engine's response curve will be a rectangle.

Otherwise, slipstream and drive smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, before I use to arrive 12th at 1:30minutes, now I'm arriving 7th at 1:05. Well it's a improvement, but I'll try change gear configurations, suspension configuration, and improve driving ... Any help is welcome :)